# Google Map android not working on other devices

Tags: android, google-maps, device

I successfully implemented google map in my application and it's running just fine on my device , but when I tried to test it on another device I got an error message "force close"

what can the problem be?

my device is samsung y pro (android 2.3)
the other device is htc (android 2.2)

thanks

Comment: post your logcat output please

Comment: actually I dont have a log cat . im installing the apk on the other device , so I dont know the exact error

Comment: So your problem is realy hard to be solved. Maybe you should consider adding crash monitor to your application first. Try to use Crashlytics: http://crashlytics.com

Comment: is it something to do with the key ? I am generating it from the debug file.

Comment: https://crashlytics.com/downloads/eclipse

Comment: download the application `logcat` from the play store and then try running the app again. You will then be able to find the stack trace of the error in there to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I understand that;

1. You don't have the device and so you can't get log cat output.
2. You have no crash report logic so you can't track crashes for your app. (I recommend crashlytics here)

I can only guess your problem; 
You are using some code/method which is not supported on 2.3 and 2.2. You can figure out this by setting your Projet Built Target to API Level 8. (From

> Projet -> Properties -> Android

path, your unsupported code for 2.2 and 2.3 will be red lined.)

Posibbly you are not using compability package's classes. Maybe you are using MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment, which is a crash casue on 2.2 and 2.3 devices.

I hope my comment helps you.

Comment: the thing is that it is working fine on 2.3 (my device) 
but 2.2 is giving and error , and I am using the support library for google map.  my minimum api level is 8.

Comment: yes but its compiling just fine. no red lines. So I suppose I have no other choice than the software you mentioned. though I wasn't able to download it I need an invitation apparently.

Comment: I got the error message. its a null pointer exception on 
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
. supposedly my map is null , but its still wierd.

Comment: i removed that line now its working fine but its not downloading the actual map. just a white screen. this is something to do with the API key?